# Expectation of $e^{ax_1^2}$ over the sphere

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

I would like to get a tight-ish estimate for the expectation of $e^{ax_1^2}$ where $x$ is drawn randomly from the unit sphere in $n$ dimensions and $x_1$ is the first coordinate.

More specifically I want to compare the expectation with $e^a$ and want to know whether the ratio

$\frac{e^a}{E[e^{ax_1^2}]}$

is bounded by an exponential in $n$ or is polynomial in $n$? (It might of course depend on $a$ and I am willing to have be logarithmic in $a$)

Comment: The bound is a constant $e^a$ which gets tighter as $n$ increases.

Comment: $x_1^2\approx\chi_1^2/n$, so $E(e^{ax_1^2})\approx (1-2a/n)^{-1/2}$, hence your ratio asymptotically is $e^a(1-a/n)$ (and a good approximation for $n>>2a$).

Comment: In simpler terms, $E(x_1^2)=1/n$ and $x_1^2$ is tightly concentrated around its mean value, so $E(e^{ax_1^2})\approx e^{a/n}\approx 1+a/n$.